How to Implement a Brush Feature in LiveCharts on blazor web assembly to Analyze Detailed Data in a Selected Range?
[enter image description here][1]I'm currently using the LiveCharts library to render temperature data charts on my website. I would like to implement a feature that allows users to select a specific range (or "brush") on the chart and then analyze the detailed data within that selected range.
For example, I'd like to achieve something similar to this image, where the selected segment of the chart is divided into 20 parts to help analyze the data in detail.
enter image description here
Here are my questions:
How can I implement the brush feature to allow users to select a range on the chart?
Once a range is selected, how can I divide it into 20 segments and display those segments on the chart?
Are there any specific methods or best practices in LiveCharts for achieving this functionality?
